# Creating Entities in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Not sure if this is possible, but it's always worth asking.

I've simplified the problem below - basically, I want to use a for loop to create multiple entities of the same kind. The problem seems to be that I can't name a new entity by calling a variable.

Can anybody think of a way round this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Key roomkey = KeyFactory.createKey("E15", "ids");

String test = "";
for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
   test = ("" + Integer.toString(x));
   Entity test = new Entity("E15", roomkey);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to create 7 entities of type `E15` with key names "0" through "6"

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
for (Integer n = 0 ; n < 7 ; ++n ) {
    Entity entity = new Entity("E15", n.toString());
    datastore.put(entity);
}
```

The last bit is important. Merely creating an instance of `Entity` doesn't persist it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an entity by aslo giving it key_name or id:

```
Entity entry = new Entity("E15", key_name, roomkey);
```

or,

```
Entity entry = new Entity("E15", id, roomkey);
```

and later you can get the entity:

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(roomkey, "E15", id);
Entity entry = datastore.get(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Entity entity = new Entity("YourKindName",String|Long);

Entity entity = new Entity("YourKindName",""+x);//using string as key
//or
Entity entity = new Entity("YourKindName",x);//using number as key
```